# How to drive a darlington transistor like TIP120 to get high gain and high collector current?

Tags: transistors, current, amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2EWCU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to wire a darlington TIP120 just to see if I can get the 1000 hfe dc gain at 100mA like it said on the data sheet. I made the circuit like it appeared in the data sheet, but wasn't successful. I was hoping for as much as 2A of output current. Is anything wrong with the circuit?

I tried to lookup some information on the datasheet for the proper pinning and see which pin is which, but it still doesn't work as expected: I applied 120 mA to the base and biased the transistor through the collector.

Comment: You can add a photo of the circuit. Use the [add image](https://i.imgur.com/aRZYPEq.png) button, the rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: apply 120 mA to the base of a darlington, it will turn hard on.

Comment: What i really wanted to ask is how do i properly wire Darlington TIP120 Transistor for amplification purpose. On the data sheet, it say a minimum of 120ma to the base to set it on but from there, i lost track of what to do next...

Comment: "On the data sheet, it say a minimum of 120ma to the base to set it on" - no it doesn't. It says 120 mA is the MAXIMUM base current.

Comment: Okay... What if it exceeds that... ?

Comment: Then you have violated the transistor specs and it may or may not be damaged or degraded. Don’t.

Comment: You need to explain what you're actually trying to do here. What are you trying to amplify and why?

Comment: Okay.. thanks so far for the contributions so far.... So what's happening is that is t possible to attain a higher output due to higher beta value with a darlington tip120, instead of a d718 transistor like it shows on this video http://sharevideo1.com/v/anRXQ25lQ0E3RzA=?t=ytb&f=co

Comment: I'll go ahead and provide a good answer for this question. It can indeed be confusing for novices, so a decent answer should help here I think.

Comment: @imranmuhd:  The link to the video doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to wire a darlington TIP120 just to see if I can get the 1000 hfe dc gain ...

> I was hoping for as much as 2A of output current.

To begin with, as far as I know, at this time, CircuitLab does not have a model for a TIP120. It has a generic model for a Darlington pair. But this model may or may not be similar to a TIP120. CircuitLab *does* however, have a model for the TIP122, which is similar.

[OnSemi's datasheet for their model of the TIP120](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf) gives a minimum \$h_{FE}\$ of 1000 for a \$V_{CE}\$ of 3.0 V. The 1.5 volts in your simulation is too low. Here is a simulation using the TIP122 at 3.0V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK69ze.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unfortunately, this model only gives a current gain of 265, which is far below what is specified in the datasheet. So, if you are attempting to model the TIP120 using CircuitLab, you are more or less out of luck with their pre-supplied transistor models. You could fiddle with parameters to get higher gain, or roll your own Darlington pair from discrete transistors. But, your results would always be open to doubt. If you really need to model a TIP120, I would use another simulator such as LTSpice.

Comment: A supply voltage of only 2V is also too low for the darlington to have a high hFE. The datasheet shows an hFE of 1000 when Vce is at least 3V so that it is not saturated.